# Scope with multiple where conditions based on multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

Is there possible to use something like

```
  scope :state, ->(state) {
    merge(where("start_time <= ? and end_time >= ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day, Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day)) if state.include?("open")
    merge(where("end_time < ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day)) if state.include?("closed")
    merge(where("start_time > ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day)) if state.include?("upcoming")
  }
```

If I use this scope, only the last one is functional.

for example:

- state(["upcoming"]) -> work
- state(["open"]) -> where is not used
- state(["deleted"], ["upcoming"]) -> only where with upcoming conditions is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this solve your problem.

```
scope :state, ->(state) {where(self.query_conditions(state), q: Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day))}

def self.query_conditions(state)
  q = ""
  q+= "start_time <= :q and end_time >= :q" if state.include?("open")
  q+= " and end_time < :q" if state.include?("closed")
  q+= " and start_time > :q" if state.include?("upcoming")
  q
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
I think there will be a problem when state open is not included because then the select will start win AND clause.

Comment: yeah, i thought of that you need to add some conditions to handle this. i just show the way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
  scope :state, ->(state) {
    rel = all
    rel = rel.where("start_time <= ? and end_time >= ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day, Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day) if state.include?("open")
    rel = rel.where("end_time < ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day) if state.include?("closed")
    rel = rel.where("start_time > ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day) if state.include?("upcoming")
    rel
  }
```

Notice that you should do

```
state(["deleted", "upcoming"])
```

instead of

```
state(["deleted"], ["upcoming"])
```

Also you can use [Array.wrap](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class) to simplify using the scope:

```
  scope :state, ->(state) {
    state = Array.wrap(state)
    rel = all
    rel = rel.where("start_time <= ? and end_time >= ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day, Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day) if state.include?("open")
    rel = rel.where("end_time < ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day) if state.include?("closed")
    rel = rel.where("start_time > ?", Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day) if state.include?("upcoming")
    rel
  }
```

With state being wrapped you can use the scope in both following ways:

```
Model.state(['open', 'upcoming'])
Model.state('open', 'upcoming')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Also, I need to combine the conditions with OR.
I Edited the answer by @Pardeep Saini, but he doesn't accept the changes yet.