# Using lambdas in scope to return records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, scope

I have the following scope to return client's with a balance.  Balance is not a field, but a function on the `Client` model.

```
def balance
    purch = self.purchases.map(&:total).sum
    pay = self.payments.sum(:amount)
    return purch - pay
end

scope :with_balance, -> { lambda {|client| { conditions: client.balance > 0}}}
```

The result of this is a `#<Proc:>` element, but I am not sure how to get the clients from it or if this approach is totally wrong.

Comment: scope :with_balance, -> { where('balance > ? ',  0) }

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "balance" does not exist`  I included the fact that its a method and not a column because you cannot perform `where` queries with mthods

Comment: you can find some help from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030775/scope-with-multiple-where-conditions-based-on-multiple-conditions/49031172#49031172

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jeremy!

`scope :with_balance, -> { lambda {|client| { conditions: client.balance > 0}}}`

There is no option for 'conditions' so I think that using 'select' is reasonable solution for filtering client who has positive balance.

My solution:

```
scope :with_balance, (lambda do
  select {|client| client.balance > 0}
end)
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I guess the only downside is that it results in an array, preventing chaining